# How to create a list of several rasters from a crop and mask (cut) from shapefile in R

Tags: r, raster, crop, mask, shapefile

I have 14 raster files from each year of land use. I would like to crop these rasters using my shapefile area of interest. With these cut rasters I would like to create a list where each element represents each year cut by the shapefile.

I tried in a very simple and fast way using the `for`, `crop` and `mask` commands, but without success.

my data exemplo:
raster and shape files : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IOGWZ3_ckKj3UoZVd7ikR5l9n04xd6He/view?usp=sharing

my code

```
    library(raster)
    library(rgdal)
    library(sf)
     
    setwd('dir')
    
    raster_solo_2005<-raster('utm-50-2005.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2006<-raster('utm-50-2006.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2007<-raster('utm-50-2007.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2008<-raster('utm-50-2008.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2009<-raster('utm-50-2009.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2010<-raster('utm-50-2010.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2011<-raster('utm-50-2011.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2012<-raster('utm-50-2012.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2013<-raster('utm-50-2013.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2014<-raster('utm-50-2014.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2015<-raster('utm-50-2015.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2016<-raster('utm-50-2016.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2017<-raster('utm-50-2017.tif')
    
    raster_solo_2018<-raster('utm-50-2018.tif')
   
 #list raster
    list_raster<-as.list(raster_solo_2005, raster_solo_2006, raster_solo_2007, raster_solo_2008, raster_solo_2009, raster_solo_2010, raster_solo_2011, raster_solo_2012, raster_solo_2013, raster_solo_2014, raster_solo_2015, raster_solo_2016, raster_solo_2017, raster_solo_2018)
      
    #shapefile
    shp_area<-sf::st_read('500m_utm.shp')
    
    #creat list empity
    list_raster_cut<-list()
      
    #loop operation
    for(i in 1:10){
      
      
      # crop e mask
      list_raster_cut[[i]] <- list_raster %>% 
        raster::crop(shp_area)%>%
        raster::mask(shp_area)
      
    }
```

Update: exit error

`Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error evaluating argument 'x' when selecting method for function 'mask': 'unable to find an inherited method for function 'crop' for signature '"list" , "sf"''`

Comment: Why does your example not work? Do you get an error or is the output wrong (and how)?

Comment: hi, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to also subset the `list_raster` object inside the `for` loop.

```
list_raster_cut[[i]] <- list_raster[[i]] %>% 
        raster::crop(shp_area)%>%
        raster::mask(shp_area)
```

Comment: it was just that. I confirmed here and it worked.